# Matching a function name

Tags: php, regex, refactoring

I need a regex that matches all instances of a particular PHP function name in given a piece of code.

The regex should match `foo` in:

```
foo("qwe");
function foo($param);
return foo();
```

An not match `foo` in:

```
my_foo("qwe");
foo_bar();
"some foo string"
```

Comment: Use a [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php)!

Comment: @Bobby Jack: looks like PHP to me. `function foo($param)` is quite indicative it's PHP, although `function foo($param);` isn't a valid PHP statement.

Comment: @Bobby Jack: I'm building a simple refactoring tool for php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\bfoo\([^\)]*\)`.
This will match "some foo() string" but not "some foo string" though. Don't know if that's good enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will want this:

```
/\bfoo\b/
```

The \b checks for word boundary. Basically the start or end of a word (which why it's on both sides).

Comment: This will match `"some foo string"`.

Comment: /^foo<rest of regular expression to catch possibilties>$/